# How to find bright fringe peaks from an image?

Tags: magnetic-fields, interference, image-processing

I am working on the Zeeman Effect lab experiment. It involves diffraction and splitting of circular fringes due to magnetic fields.

I have taken pictures of the interference pattern, described by a set of bright fringes. Now, I need to measure radii of the fringes from the center.

**However,** I am trying to find a software that could analyze the images and tell me where exactly the peak of light intensity is in each fringe, in order to make the radius measurements from there. Any ideas for software like that?

Comment: Please add some sample Images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could just plot the image intensity along a line through the center of the circular fringes. Like I did here, showing the "densitometer data" in the upper panel, and the lower half of the image data in the lower panel.

[image]

Comment: May I know the software you used for the plot? Thank you!

Comment: @H.Dayekh I made this long ago, I do not quite remember how. But I may have loaded the image as 2D data in some mathematical plotting software (probably Mathematica, or Igor from Wavemetrix). And then chose one column or one row to plot the intensity along a horizontal or vertical line through the center of the pattern. And maybe I added 3 or 5 of such arrays together. (One can try more sophisticated operations which would extract more information from the data, but that is not what I did for this image.)